# Create and Alter Excel tables using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to create and alter Excel Tables using apache POI?

There is class that represents an Excel table (http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html) and there are two methods createTable and getTables (http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createTable()) in the API, but the API does not explains how to manipulate the XSSFTable object in order to select the cell range of the table

Answer (score 0):

JExcelAPi may actually be better and more manageable. I have used both. However, it is incorrect to say that JExcelAPI by Andy Khan is built over POI. It is a full fledged Java implementation in its own right, where you can take the source code and make changes to it.

Answer (score -1):

There is library, which is built on top of POI - [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)
I think you can do one of two:

1. Look, how it's implemented in JExcelApi and do it in the same way
2. Just use JExcelApi